# Like something on facebook via android

Tags: android, facebook

I have a valid session for Facebook in my android Facebook class. I would like to "like" a URL (Facebook page). Is there any way to do this without using webview?

```
mFacebook.authorize(this, premArr, new LoginDialogListener());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code :

```
mFacebookLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.fbjs.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=30&height=55&action=like&colorscheme=light&href=<your URL here>"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, This will open browser and we can like the page. but how i will get a like successfull result to complete my functionality?

Comment: you need to do startActivityForResult

Comment: i mean how i can control the new browser intent. i need to close the intent if like successful or not and also need to do some functionality depending up on the result.

Comment: please help me to add div and javascript to a webview